# Don't close infoWindow on map clicked in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(geom.get(0)).title(id).visible(true);
googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
```

I have trying with this code but unable to keep the infowindow in open mode on map click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this , 
If infowindow is closed on map click , show it again

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    //mMarker is the shown marker 
                    if (mMarker != null)
                        mMarker.showInfoWindow();

                }
            });
```

Comment: here what is **mMarker** ?

Comment: store a global reference to the added marker , for which infoWindow is shown. e.g.    mMarker= googleMap.addMarker(marker); mMarker.showInfoWindow();   // In your case (variable mMarker is class variable)

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    if (marker.isInfoWindowShown()==true)
                    {
                        marker.hideInfoWindow();
                    }
                }
            });
```